# Asking for a method used in data mining(especially for blog webpages)

Tags: data-mining

recently I attended a talk on data-mining,and I missed some points by the lecturer,which is about a technique used on data-mining,and which is especially useful for blog webpages.
I think I sort of remembered the term is named as "td/tdf" something,but really not sure.
I googled for this for a while,still have no result.

It would be great if you could point out what this technique is,since I want to look further into this topic.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's tf/idf, see [Vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you mean [temporal difference learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference_learning).

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments, actual answer is [Term Frequency / Inverse Document Frequency](http://www.iva.dk/bh/core%20concepts%20in%20lis/articles%20a-z/tf_idf.htm).